# Identify wordpress blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to edit a wordpress-theme (translations that are hardcoded in the theme etc) and stumble upon a problem here:
How do I identify, where a content block comes from? 
Like, if my theme is constructed by 3 files post.php header.php and footer.php (which would make things pretty simple, but in my case it's quite some more files) and the content isn't set there consistently and the naming is neither "semantic", how could I identify that compiled block abc comes from header.php?

Is that something that can be done via Firebug/DevTools?

Although this question is specifically aiming at Wordpress as a system, the same problem occurs with other file-heavy systems like Typo3 or Magento. Isn't there some other routine then opening, searching all existing files?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I would download a copy of the website and use a program like notepad++ to search through the whole website for some specific to that block.

Comment: like @Howlin said, but not the whole page, only the template. N++ has a "find in files" search option

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is translation-ready, you could try using [Poedit](http://poedit.net/). If not, you can identify where a block comes from knowing that:

**Header.php:** you'll find there all the strings that come in every page of your blog. Normaly Header.php includes all the code from the beginning of the HTML document until body, but it can be different from one theme to another. There may be diferrents headers, like header-gallery.php (for galleries) or similars.

**Index.php:** That's the index of your blog, normally it includes the code from the BODY of the html document for the index page.

**Single.php, Page.php, Content.php, Aside.php or similars:** They include the code for the body of every post/page type. For instance, single.php includes the BODY code for the single post. Sometiems, instead of single.php there are another options like content.php, content-wide.php or similars ("content-TypeOfPage.php"

**Footer.php:** It closes the HTML document for every post/page. Normaly it includes from the last lines before closing the BODY until the closing of the HTML tag.

**Functions.php:**: Take care editing this one. This file and the other files required/included on it include the code for the settings of the theme and any other functions implemented. For instance, the custom admin pages on the Dashboard are coded there.

Comment: No, the theme must be translation-ready. Hardcoded strings can only be edited directly modifying the code :/